# Como arrumar escala de eixo y secundário pelo ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Gostaria de saber como prosseguir para rearranjar a escala do eixo y secundário do meu gráfico.

```
Sal = c(36.45,36.41,36.22,35.94,35.67,35.81,35.19,34.89,35.31,
        34.67,36.16,35.95,35.89,36.03,36.05,36.09,36.18)
Temp = c(28.13,28.10,28.16,28.33,28.11,28.03,28.71,29.18,29.60,
         29.36,29.11,29.12,28.86,29.12,28.73,28.36,28.17)
Lat2 = c(-1:15)

data2 = data.frame(Latitude = Lat2, Salinidade = Sal, Temperatura = Temp)

p1 <- ggplot(data2, aes(x = Lat2, y = Temperatura)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = "Temperature (°C)")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Salinidade, color = "Salinity"))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-1,15)) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*1, name="Salinity"))+
  labs(x = "Latitude", y = "Temperature", color = "") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("orange2", "gray50")) +
  theme_bw()

p1
```

[image: gráfico]

Meu objetivo era fazer com que as linhas de temperatura e salinidade se cruzassem, mas não consigo mexer na escala do segundo eixo y. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Até onde sei, não há uma maneira automatizada de fazer isso. O truque que uso em situações como essa é aplicar a uma transformação adequada aos dados da segunda `geom_line` e do argumento `sec_axis`. Nesse caso, `-7` e `+7`, respectivamente.

```r
library(ggplot2)

Sal = c(36.45,36.41,36.22,35.94,35.67,35.81,35.19,34.89,35.31,
        34.67,36.16,35.95,35.89,36.03,36.05,36.09,36.18)
Temp = c(28.13,28.10,28.16,28.33,28.11,28.03,28.71,29.18,29.60,
         29.36,29.11,29.12,28.86,29.12,28.73,28.36,28.17)
Lat2 = c(-1:15)

data2 = data.frame(Latitude = Lat2, Salinidade = Sal, Temperatura = Temp)

ggplot(data2, aes(x = Lat2, y = Temperatura)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = "Temperature (°C)")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Salinidade-7, color = "Salinity"))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-1,15)) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . +7, name="Salinity"))+
  labs(x = "Latitude", y = "Temperature", color = "") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("orange2", "gray50")) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Por que 7 e não 6 ou 8? Porque sim. Achei que 7 é um bom valor para a translação vertical desejada. Tentei com outros valores e essa acabou sendo a opção que mais me agradou.

Comment: Perfeito! Ficou exatamente como eu queria! Obrigada!! Li em algum lugar que o ggplot2 não tem uma forma automatizada de fazer isso, pois em geral, gráficos com dois eixos y podem ser trabalhosos de ser interpretados. No meu caso, é absolutamente necessário hehe. Obrigada mais uma vez! <3

Comment: Exatamente! É um procedimento complicado justamente para desencorajar o seu uso, mas tem vezes em que temos que apelar para ele.

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira de ter os eixos em escalas que possam ser traçadas no mesmo gráfico é definir um fator de conversão do eixo vertical esquerdo para o direito. No código abaixo faço isso com `range` e divisão `/`. Depois é só tomar o máximo como fator de conversão.

Duas instruções e a adaptação do código para os eixos chegam:

- Multiplica-se o eixo da esquerda pelo fator `fac`;
- divide-se o eixo da direita também por `fac`.

Nada garante que isto funciona em todos os casos mas funciona bem muitas vezes.

```r
library(ggplot2)

Sal = c(36.45,36.41,36.22,35.94,35.67,35.81,35.19,34.89,35.31,
        34.67,36.16,35.95,35.89,36.03,36.05,36.09,36.18)
Temp = c(28.13,28.10,28.16,28.33,28.11,28.03,28.71,29.18,29.60,
         29.36,29.11,29.12,28.86,29.12,28.73,28.36,28.17)
Lat2 = -1:15

data2 = data.frame(Latitude = Lat2, Salinidade = Sal, Temperatura = Temp)

(fac <- with(data2, range(Temperatura)/range(Salinidade)))
#> [1] 0.8084800 0.8120713
fac <- max(fac)

ggplot(data2, aes(x = Lat2, y = Temperatura)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = "Temperature (°C)")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Salinidade * fac, color = "Salinity"))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-1,15)) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / fac, name="Salinity"))+
  labs(x = "Latitude", y = "Temperature", color = "") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("orange2", "gray50")) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: O gráfico até modificou... ficou mais parecido com o que eu havia feito no OriginPro. Obrigada!